ArcGIS Pro loads raster with spaces in file path on C: drive, but not other drives
I recently moved my GIS folder from my C: drive to a second storage drive (E:), and am having trouble loading rasters. I narrowed the issue to spaces in the file path - but I can't figure out why this is not a problem for Arc when accessing files on the C: drive, where it is installed. My best guess is that it is a permissions issue - C: has a permission for the principle below that I couldn't easily add to E:, but even when I did manage to add it, the problem persisted.
"Account Unknown(S-1-15-3-65536-1888954469-739942743-1668119174-2468466756-4239452838-1296943325-355587736-700089176)"
Any recommendations? I can remove spaces in the file path, but if I want to back up to OneDrive (which I currently do on C: with no file path issues) this would be unavoidable.

Maybe your E: drive is formatted into another file system than C:. I do not know what effect it could have, but check it anyway.

Unless I'm missing something else, they're both NTFS.

Is the trouble you are having loading any rasters in any projects, new or old, or are you only having trouble with existing projects loading rasters already in them?  Were the problem rasters moved with your GIS folder to E or were they located somewhere else and unchanged?  Did you move the entire folder from C to E or did you move files or blocks of files into a new folder?  What file types are the problem rasters?  If the problem is existing projects were you using absolute or relative paths?

At some point, I believe ESRI declared ArcGIS Pro officially incompatible with OneDrive. I don't know if more recent updates have solved that. You might consider doing all of your work locally and then just backing your work up to OneDrive at the end of each session.
